# Which data structure (full HABTM ?)

Tags: data-structures, has-and-belongs-to-many, has-one

I just want to know which of this two structures is the best for better performance:

- Full [HABTM](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) (many to many), but with a very big join table (so only one association for query)
- Or, HABTM + 1 hasOne (which reduce significantly the join table rows (equal to number of main entity, approximatively 50 000rows) ? But this method forced me to do a query with 2 associations.

So to sum up. Should I use a query with a single association but a big join table (120 000rows) or use a query for 2 associations but with a more lightweight join table ?

Comment: Try http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. I believe the main factor in the performance is the database architecture, the framework/language used being secondary.

Comment: Try both and measure. Only way to know.

Comment: Thanks for your advices.

Comment: As already suggested, the DBMS will have major impact on the performance for this type of problem. For n:m I would usually recommend Object Databases, they are much better for this kind of relations and do not need separate join-tables. They basically allow using non-first normal form (N1NF) by allowing (ideally indexable) direct references, without needing a 'join'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reflexions, I think I will use a single join.
I have just seen some benchmarks that shows single join  will be more efficient than multiple queries even if the join table contain lot of rows. It's also less development effort for my application code.

I remain at your listening for any advice.
Thanks

Comment: It's ok to accept your own answer. It helps people find questions without accepted answers. Would a better answer come up, you would be able to accept it later on.